# Hard (ambiguously-worded) probability question

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm given the following question:
[image]

I have no idea how to approach it; I'm not sure entirely what it's asking.

I suppose I could use the fact that $Corr(B,C)=\frac{Cov(B,C)}{Var(B) \cdot Var(C)} \iff0.7=\frac{E[BC]-10.8(10.8)}{0.0170^2 \cdot 0.0170^2}$ which yields $E[BC]=116.64...$, but, then, what do I do with this information?

Also, what, algebraically, is the question asking me to find (i.e. $E[\text{what?}]$: I'm not sure what it means by a 'junction').

In addition, I know how to calculate $\sigma_{\text{something}}$, but of what, in this case?
Thanks

Comment: Since the four components are fitted together, I think it is asking you to find $E[A+B+C+D]$ and $\mathrm{var}[A+B+C+D]$. The first can be computed easily using linearity of expectation. The second computation requires you to take into account the pairwise covariances of the components.

Comment: Thanks! Is the correlation between any pair, not both of which are $B$ and $C$, $0$?

Comment: No problem! I believe it is assumed so, as the problem states, "Assuming all other correlations between lengths of components of different types are zero".